# gitlab-pages: artifact is not unzipped, how to get logs ?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pages

I am trying to use gitlab-pages. It generates artifacts, but fails to unzip the result. I would like to know a command that would help me to get the logs in order to understand what is happening !

Regarding the ci yaml file, I setup everything alright, I think. In the end, on the server side:

```
root@gitlab-datalab:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared# pwd
/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared
```

I got an artifact

```
root@gitlab-datalab:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared# ls -la  artifacts/2017_11/6/543/
total 1856
drwxr-xr-x 2 git git    4096 Nov 14 16:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 git git    4096 Nov 14 16:38 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 git git 1882245 Nov 14 16:38 artifacts.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 git git    4163 Nov 14 16:38 metadata.gz
```

Yet pages directory is empty

```
root@gitlab-datalab:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared# ls -la pages/
total 8
drwxr-x--- 2 git gitlab-www 4096 Nov 14 16:23 .
drwxrwxrwx 6 git gitlab-www 4096 Mar  2  2017 ..
```

I have no clue on how to get more information. Where can I find some logs ?

Thx !

Comment: check the page logs using `gitlab-ctl tail gitlab-pages`

Comment: I tried, but got absolutely no clue on the "artifacts" caching process. I ended up setting an apache server where i directly dump the documentation pages, a process which is triggered by a regular "job" in gitlab-ci

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in gitlab-ce, if zip is not installed in the runner, which should have been fixed in 2017

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/2020

A workaround is to force the runner to install zip package - add this in the ci before_script.

```
apt-get update && apt-get install unzip
```

(https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/28583#note_24042681)